# Iterate over fields in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have data as follows:

```
(000001, mfp=621|mdus=4.0|mduc=5.0|mas=1|mpc=4.0|mfn=1|country=ABC)
(00002, address=1000+mity|mus=1|name=kailtig+bksyt|mas=1|mpc=4.977552|country=ABC)
```

The first field is an identifier while second field contains a set of attributes. The attribute field is not consistent, i.e., it may sometimes contain address attribute, and sometimes not.

What I have to do is for each identifier, I have to find if the attribute field contains address and/country country or not, and have my output as follows:

```
 000001, ,country=ABC
 00002,address=105000+myCity,country=ABC
```

I am new to pig and do not have much idea. But, what I was thinking was,

1. create a tuple by splitting the attribute field,
2. iterate over each field in the tuple, and check if it matches address

   1. if it matches, output it.
3. check if it matches country

   1. if it matches, output it

I want to ask is if there is any way to iterate over the fields in the tuple? Or any other ways to solve this task.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression to extract the fields you want.  You could also write a UDF to convert your structure into a map, but that is probably overkill in this case.

```
DUMP A;
(000001, mfp=621|mdus=4.0|mduc=5.0|mas=1|mpc=4.0|mfn=1|country=ABC)
(00002, address=1000+mity|mus=1|name=kailtig+bksyt|mas=1|mpc=4.977552|country=ABC)
DESCRIBE A;
{(id:chararray, attributes:chararray)}

B =
    FOREACH A
    GENERATE
        id,
        REGEX_EXTRACT(attributes, 'address=[^|]+', 0),
        REGEX_EXTRACT(attributes, 'country=[^|]+', 0);
```

See `REGEX_EXTRACT` [here](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/udf_lists.html).